# DashboardMenuItem active resource

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I wanted to see how I do to know within DashboardMenuItem which resource is active, since I want to add a Divider below it. Some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is here:

You have to modify the RaMenuItemLink css class

https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/09/11/react-admin-tutorials-build-your-own-theme.html